# All Domains Missing After Plesk Parallels Upgrade From 11 To 12

Tags: upgrade, plesk, parallels

I've just used the Parallels upgrade service (`autoinstaller` in terminal). I upgraded from Parallels 11 to 12. I logged into the panel, it asked me all the personal info and I started to get nervous.

Now that I am properly logged in, all my 165 customers and domains are missing!?! I've checked on the server, and the data is still present in the `/var/www/vhosts` directories, although nothing shows up in Parallels.

I've also looked through the Parallels docs/forums/help but I can't find any starting points, apart from this very helpful suggestion to restore the server from backup: http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/11190

Is there any way I can roll back to eleven? And, is there any chance I can get my domains/customers/sites/dignity back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, Plesk keeps all data related to customer details, domain and hosting settings in psa database.

If these tables are empty in your server, plesk will not list any domain in domains list even though the contents exists in /var/www/vhosts directories.

In your case I believe upgrade, went wrong somewhere and your psa database is empty now.
As Plesk never allows downgrading versions, I suggest you to follow below steps to recover ur old database and domains list:

1. Enter to /var/lib/psa/dumps directory.
2. Choose a backup of psa database which was created just before u did the upgrade. Unzip it and the restore this using below command:

   mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa < your.backup.file.sql
3. Now login to psa and make confirm what is the psa database version:

select * from misc where param='version';

You will see db version will be 11 one, now make it manually 12 compatible by changing version in misc table:

Update misc set val='' where param='version';

1. Now run bootstrapper to repair it.
   /usr/local/psa/bootstrapper/pp12.0.18....../bootstrapper.sh repair

This will upgrade psa to 12 compatible db as well as your contents will now display in Plesk.

Any further difficulties please let me know here.

Answer (score 1):

For future adventurers; Parallels creates a daily backup of the **mysql**, **psa** and **information_schema** databases. In addition to this, it also creates pre-upgrade and pre-remove backups of the databases.

By default, on CentOS 6.4, the dump directory is at `/var/lib/psa/dumps/`. Happy hunting!